# После нажатия на кнопку в селект меню не вылезает модальное окно, уже много у кого спросил, однако ошибку найти так и не могу

Tags: discord, modal, disnake

Ошибки в консоли так же не вылезает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Сам код]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.